# mootools add/remove table rows dynamically with HtmlTable Class

Tags: html-table, row, addition, mootools

How can I remove my table row onClick event?

```
    var count = 0,
        optionsTable     = new HtmlTable({
                properties: {id: 'optionstable', border: 0, cellspacing: 0, width: "100%"},
                headers: ['Name', 'Value', 'Price', 'Action']                               
            }).inject(container);

        optionsTable.push(['<input type="text" name="option[0][name]" class="w70">',
                   '<input type="text" name="option[0][value]" class="w50">',
                   '<input type="text" name="option[0][price]" class="w50">',
                   '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_option">Add</a>'
                 ]);

        $$('.add_option').addEvent('click', function(){
            count ++;
            optionsTable.push(['<input type="text" name="option['+count+'][name]" class="w70">',
               '<input type="text" name="option['+count+'][value]" class="w50">',
               '<input type="text" name="option['+count+'][price]" class="w50">',
               '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="product_remove_option">Remove</a>'
           ]);
        });

        $$('.product_remove_option').addEvent('click', function(){
            /*What should be here to remove selected table row?*/                        
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should make sure to always add events to newly created elements (or use event delegation).

To answer your question: The `HtmlTable.push` method returns an object containing the added table row and table cells. You can simply call `destroy` on the table row to remove it.

Here's how the code should look:

```
var count = 0,
    optionsTable     = new HtmlTable({
            properties: {id: 'optionstable', border: 0, cellspacing: 0, width: "100%"},
            headers: ['Name', 'Value', 'Price', 'Action']                               
        }).inject(container);

var firstRow = optionsTable.push(['<input type="text" name="option[0][name]" class="w70">',
           '<input type="text" name="option[0][value]" class="w50">',
           '<input type="text" name="option[0][price]" class="w50">',
           '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_option">Add</a>'
         ]);

firstRow.tr.getElement('.add_option').addEvent('click', function(){
    count ++;
    var newRow = optionsTable.push(['<input type="text" name="option['+count+'][name]" class="w70">',
       '<input type="text" name="option['+count+'][value]" class="w50">',
       '<input type="text" name="option['+count+'][price]" class="w50">',
       '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="product_remove_option">Remove</a>'
    ]);
    newRow.tr.getElement('.product_remove_option').addEvent('click', function(){
        newRow.tr.destroy();
    });                   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
$('optionstable').getElements('tr').addEvent('click',function(){
  this.destroy();
});
```